# SQL How can I create an inner join from these 2 tables

Tags: sql

I am just learning sql and I am creating a social network as a learning experience . I have 2 tables called **Streams** and **Votes**, Streams  pulls user created content and Votes stores the content that people have liked  . What I am trying to figure out is how can I return the data from both tables to check if a user a liked a particular post being shown . For instance this is how both my tables look . If you see they both have a field in common **stream_id** and they both have number 278. How can I do an inner join that checks to see if there are any common stream_ID in both tables ? This is the sql code that I use that gets me the Stream data

**Query 1**

```
select post,profile_id,
votes,id as stream_id FROM streams WHERE latitudes>=28.1036 AND
            28.9732>=latitudes AND longitudes>=-81.8696 AND -80.8798>=longitudes 
            order by id desc limit 10
```

The User ID is 11 and both Streams.profile_id and Votes.my_id are the same field . I have tried this SQL query but this only returns in total 1 result . Again I would like to return all results from the Streams table which I do in query 1 and also add another column to the results from the Votes table where Votes.stream_id=Streams.ID because it'll show that the particular user has liked that post. Any hemp would be great

**Query 2**

```
select s.post,s.profile_id,
s.votes,s.id as stream_id, v.my_id as ID  FROM streams s inner join Votes v on (s.id = v.stream_id) WHERE latitudes>=28.1036 AND
            28.9732>=latitudes AND longitudes>=-81.8696 AND -80.8798>=longitudes 
            order by id desc limit 10
```

**Streams**
[image: Streams Table]

**Votes**
[image: Votes Table]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT s.post, s.profile_id, s.votes, s.id as stream_id, v.my_id as ID  
FROM streams s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Votes v on (s.id = v.stream_id) WHERE latitudes>=28.1036 AND
        28.9732>=latitudes AND longitudes>=-81.8696 AND -80.8798>=longitudes 
        order by id desc limit 10
```

For more information about joins, look [here](http://www.sql-join.com/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for a LEFT JOIN

```
 select s.post,s.profile_id,
     s.votes,s.id as stream_id, v.my_id as ID  FROM streams s LEFT JOIN Votes v on (s.id = v.stream_id) WHERE latitudes>=28.1036 AND
                 28.9732>=latitudes AND longitudes>=-81.8696 AND -80.8798>=longitudes 
                 order by id desc limit 10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help